# Writing to sheet leads to "name already taken"

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, excel-interop

I'm learning how to use Interop.Excel. The test Winforms program reads an existing Excel file, checks if a tab names "Added_by_program" exists, deletes the sheet if it does, and creates a new sheet named "Added_by_program." If I don't try to write to the new sheet, the program runs perfectly, over and over. I get problems when I try to write to it. If the sheet is not present in the original file, the program runs perfectly one time, and writes correctly to the newly created sheet. but on subsequent runs, I get:

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'That name is already taken. Try a different one.'"

for the line that tries to name the new sheet. I have to manually kill the open Excel instance. What am I missing?

Code (irrelevant lines taken out)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace excelReadWrite
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string readFolder = myPath;

    string inFileName = @"Aram test excel file.xlsx";
    string newSheetName = "Added_by_program";
    Range rawRange = null;
    Range pasteRange = null;
    int rawCols = 0;
    int rawRows = 0;
    int iInSheet = 0;
    int iNewSheet = 0;
    int nInSheets = 0;     
    bool foundRawSheet = false;
    bool foundNewSheet = false;
    Worksheet worksheet = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void start_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inFile = myPath+ inFileName;
        int nSheets = 0;
        string sheetNames = "";

        // Open Excel workbook to read
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Workbook workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(inFile);

        // Count worksheets in opened Excel file
        nSheets = workbook.Worksheets.Count;
        nSheets_TextBox.Text = nSheets.ToString();

        nInSheets = 0;
        foreach (Worksheet worksheet in workbook.Worksheets)
            ++nInSheets;

            //foreach (Worksheet worksheet in workbook.Worksheets)
            for (int iSheet = nInSheets; iSheet >= 1; --iSheet)
        {
            worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[iSheet];
            sheetNames  += " " + worksheet.Name;

            // The program is going to add a worksheet. If it already exists, delete it before adding it.
            if (string.Equals(worksheet.Name, newSheetName))
            {
                workbook.Worksheets[iSheet].Delete();
            }
        }


        // Add a new sheet and name it
        if (foundRawSheet)
        {
         newWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add();

         newWorksheet.Name = newSheetName;
// THE NEXT LINE IS THE PROBLEM LINE
// "Written" WILL BE WRITTEN TO A1:C3 WHEN THE SHEET IS CREATED, BUT THIS LINE
// CAUSES THE ERROR IN SUBSEQUENT RUNS 
// IF I COMMENT IT OUT, THE PROGRAM RUNS FINE, REPEATEDLY
         newWorksheet.Range["A1", "C3"].Value2 = "Written";

        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close();
        xl.Quit();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Your code never sets `foundRawSheet` to true, so that last `if` block shouldn't be running...

Comment: TIm --. foundRawSheet does get set, but in an unrelated part of the code, so I deleted in my post out for brevity. Sorry, that was definitely misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `xl.DisplayAlerts=false`?

If not, deleting a worksheet with existing data will cause a confirm dialog to be displayed.  .

If the Excel application is visible, the `Worksheet.Delete` will block until the dialog is acknowledged.

If the Excel application is not visible, your code execution will proceed (the dialog is effectively canceled --> delete not confirmed), but the worksheet will not be deleted.